# electron: loading image into new window

Tags: javascript, html, electron

In an electron application, I am trying to display an image from the local disc in a window
that opens when a button in the main window is clicked.
The image's path is known at runtime only.
My first approach was to generate a new window that loads a template html-file
when the click event on that button is triggered and then set the
src-attribute of the img-element in this html template,
but I did not succeed in getting a handle on this img-element defined in
"imgView.html" (the following is from the renderer-process):

```
newWindowBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    let win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
         nodeIntegration: true
         },
         width: 500, height:500});
    win.loadFile("imgView.html");
    // how can the img-element defined in the template imgView.html
    // be accessed here to set the src-attribute?
    win.show();
    win.on('close', function(){win=null})
})
```

I want to be able to have several windows open at the same time, with different images loaded.
My second approach was to dynamically generate the html to be loaded:

```
var html = [
"<body>",
"<p>Sample image: </p>",
"<img src=\"img.png\" style=\"width:90%\">",
"</body>"
].join("")
```

and replace the `win.loadFile` command in the `newWindowBtn.addEventListener` event-function
from above with

```
    win.loadURL("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(html),
    {baseURLForDataURL: __dirname + "/imgDir/"}
    )
```

but apparently the image is not found (the rest of the page is loaded ok).
I played around with the format of `baseURLForDataURL`, but nothing worked.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, I viewed that `data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(html)` is not sufficient and you need to encode the html with base64: `data:text/html;base64, + btoa(html)`.

**Pay Attention**
If this isn't a solution, this means that Electron doesn't allow to you to call the image because the page you'd like to load is considered an external page and you must encode the image with base64, too.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have not found the module ```btoa``` - is it some third-party extension for Node.js? I wonder if the problem at hand cannot be solved somehow with just standard Node/electron modules (either by dynamically passing data like a file path to the new window or by dynamically generating the html as attempted above)...

Comment: btoa is not a module, it's a simple function implemented with javascript, and it's a native browser function: you don't need to create or add modules or functions...